# Error CS0103 The name 'Web' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, winforms

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace браузер_аля_
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void back_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Web.GoBack();
        }

        private void Front_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Web.GoForward();
        }

        private void Home_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {           Web.Navigate("https://www.ena.lp.edu.ua:8080//");
        }

        private void Refresh_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Web.Refresh();
        }

        private void toolStripTextBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }

        private void Enter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Web.Navigate(toolStrip1.Text);
        }

        private void Web_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            toolStrip1.Text = Web.Url.ToString();
        }
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Web.Navigate("www.yandex.com/");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: у вас нет переменной `Web` в классе `Form1`, надо её добавить

Comment: если же вы уверены, что она есть, то покажите код дизайнера формы

Comment: @iKuzmychov Скорее всего, не переменной, а поля или свойств. Если это новичок, то это важно, если он будет что-нибудь гуглить по этой теме. Локальная переменная - то, что находится внутри какого-то метода; у них область видимости ограничивается методом, в котором они были объявлены. Так же и их "время жизни" ограничивается методом. Конечно, бывалые бы вас поняли, но для новичка, как мне кажется, правильные термины являются крайней важной штукой

Comment: соглашусь, корректнее тут будет сказать, скорее всего, "поле"